# Removing whitespaces or %20 in url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hi guys can you help me here im having a little trouble here im tring to use the htaccess to remove all 20% in my url and replacing it with hyphen I manage to get rid the other 20% in between the words Acer,Liquid,S1,S510

here is my url **/localhost/gadgets/product/Acer-Liquid-S1-S510%20Mobile**

As you can see there is one %20 in last part, how can I remove it

And here is my htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gadgets/

Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^brand/([a-zA-Z]+)$ brand.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   product.php?product_name=$1-$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s%20]+(.+)$ $1$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\s%20]+(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: no need of htaccess.Can be done by url encoding.

Comment: @Sunil Im not comfortable to use url encoding im just comfortable using htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gadgets/

RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,E=Redirect:1]

RewriteCond {ENV:Redirect} ^1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^brand/([a-zA-Z]+)$ brand.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ product.php?product_name=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The first rule removes all the whitespaces in a loop (using `[N]`) so we don't have to specify multiple `RewriteRules` doing it one by one now.

The next rule (with `{ENV:Redirect}` condition) is optional and is used to reflect the use of hyphens on the client's browser as well so that any bookmarks created link to the correct non-whitespaced version of the URL.

Comment: Interesting approach of creating a “loop”, +1. Do you know whether this is affected by the [`LimitInternalRecursion`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion) setting?

Comment: Ravi  your suggestion just gives an infinite "waiting for localhost"

Comment: CBroe nope its affected by LimitInternalRecursion I've check the error log in apache, I dont know how I fix it now

Comment: @magnum2236 Can you try again with `DPI` added as `[N,DPI,E=Redirect:1]`?

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal sir I've tried your suggestion which is [N,DPI,E=Redirect:1] and the result is I was thrown back to my homepage instead of the product

Comment: @magnum2236 Check update. Notice you were also missing the `[L]` flag in your `brand.php` rule.

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal I put the [L] and the [N,DPI,E=Redirect:1] flag but the result is still the same I was back to my homepage

Comment: No, just paste the complete update as is. If it doesn't work provide the site url you're having troubles with.