# Replace all forward slashes with dashes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are a few [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279681/mod-rewrite-replace-underscores-with-dashes) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337555/mod-rewrite-replace-all-slashes) on SO, but none that work for this specific scenario.

I want to replace all forward slashes in a URL path with dashes, using `mod_rewrite`.

So https://stackoverflow.com/foo/bar/baz should redirect to https://stackoverflow.com/foo-bar-baz.

There could be any number of segments in the path (between forward slashes).

I think the solution involves the [N flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n), but every attempt I've made results in an endless loop.

Comment: Which version of Apache?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28849327/removing-whitespaces-or-20-in-url-using-htaccess

Comment: @CBroe Doesn't work for forward slashes

Comment: @ank: That’s a brilliant problem description.

Comment: @CBroe The solution you linked to, when modified for forward slashes, results in an endless loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1-$2 [NE,L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1-$2
```

This will redirect `example.com/foo/bar/baz/abc/xyz/123` to `example.com/foo-bar-baz-abc-xyz-123`

Comment: this works perfectly - are you able to explain it, i.e. why the two steps?

Comment: Yes sure. First rule will execute only when there is only forward slash to be replaced so will be skipped until last `/`. 2nd rule will keep executing multiple times replacing each `/` by `-` until one `/` is left.

Comment: Why does the second one keep executing multiple times without the `N` flag?

Comment: `N` is not needed for looping, that is default Apache behavior. As long as there is any matching rule for the current URI that rule will be executed.

Comment: That's great thanks mate. Could you swap the rules? As the first one gets executed last? Or is it in that order for URLs with only one forward slash to replace?

Comment: Ordering is important here. As soon an one slash is remaining a redirect should take place.

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite without redirect?

Comment: Just remove `R=302` from above rule.

Comment: Works for me. If you want example.com/directory/foo/bar/baz/abc/xyz/123 to direct to example.com/directory/foo-bar-baz-abc-xyz-123  just do RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /directory/$1-$2 [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /directory/$1-$2   -- That's how I have mine setup and it's working. 301 instead of 302 should permanently redirect search engines to the new URL

Comment: how to do this in nginx?